# Getting text in <td> element using SpecFlow and Selenium

Tags: unit-testing, selenium, visual-studio-2012, selenium-webdriver, specflow

I am getting an error in my *SpecFlow* unit test:

> System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException : The given key was not present in the dictionary.
>      at TechTalk.SpecFlow.SpecFlowContext.Get[T](String key)
>      at F*****.Live.PS.*******.Steps.*******.EnterStagingDateAndSaveSteps.ThenUserSeesInNEXTRE_ENROLMENTWINDOWTextFieldInPENSIONASSESSMENTDATESPageInPENSIONModule(String p0) in c:\Git\LivePeopleSystemTests\Fourth.Live.PS.AutomationTests\F*****.Live.PS.*******.Steps*******\EnterStagingDateAndSaveSteps.cs:line 175

Here is the referenced method in `EnterStagingDateAndSaveSteps.cs`

```
[Then(@"user sees ""(.*)"" in NEXT RE-ENROLMENT WINDOW Text Field in PENSION ASSESSMENT DATES page in PENSION module")]
    public void ThenUserSeesInNEXTRE_ENROLMENTWINDOWTextFieldInPENSIONASSESSMENTDATESPageInPENSIONModule(string p0)
    {
        // GetNextReEnrollmentWindow
        string validator =
            ScenarioContext.Current.Get<PensionAssessmentDates>("_nextReEnrollmentWindow")
                .GetNextReEnrollmentWindow();
        Assert.IsTrue(validator == p0);
    }
```

(I also tried `return Driver.WaitAndGetText(_nextReEnrollmentWindow);` in there)

so it looks like the key `_nextReEnrollmentWindow` doesn't exist, but here it is defined in **PensionAssessmentDates.cs**:

```
private readonly By _nextReEnrollmentWindow = By.Id("NextReEnrollmentWindow");
```

[image]

The `PensionAssessmentSteps` is set into the *ScenarioContext.Current* like this:

```
    [Then(@"user sees ""(.*)"" in NEXT RE-ENROLMENT WINDOW Text Field in PENSION ASSESSMENT DATES page in PENSION module")]
    public void ThenUserSeesInNEXTRE_ENROLMENTWINDOWTextFieldInPENSIONASSESSMENTDATESPageInPENSIONModule(string p0)
    {
        // GetNextReEnrollmentWindow
        string validator =
            ScenarioContext.Current.Get<PensionAssessmentDates>("_nextReEnrollmentWindow")
                .GetNextReEnrollmentWindow();
        Assert.IsTrue(validator == p0);
    }
```

and here is the actual web-page I am trying to test showing the element exists:

[image]

I'd be grateful for any pointers or advice on what I have missed which is causing my unit test to stop as below:

```
 EnterStagingDateAndSaveSteps.WhenUserClicksSAVEButtonUnderAUTOMATICENROLMENTATSTAGINGDATEFrameInPENSIONASSESSMENTDATESPageInPENSIONModule() (0.7s)
Then user sees "02 Oct 2019 to 02 Apr 2020" in NEXT RE-ENROLMENT WINDOW Text Field in PENSION ASSESSMENT DATES page in PENSION module
-> error: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
```

Comment: where do you set the `PensionAssessmentDates` into the `ScenarioContext.Current`? I have a feeling you have a fundamental misunderstanding about how this works...

Comment: @SamHolder: Hi Sam, it's in the file `EnterStagingDateAndSaveSteps.cs` - I will add that code with an edit...

Comment: @SamHolder: yes it's definitely possible that I have missed something fundamental!

Comment: your edit shows accessing the `Get` twice, not using the `Set`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ScenarioContext.Current.Get` and `Set` methods simply allow you to add an object to the dictionary of values attached to the current scenario using a key.

Once you have added an element to the dictionary in one step, you can retrieve it in another step. The exception you are getting implies that you have not added anything to the dictionary using the key `_nextReEnrollmentWindow`.

Do you call `ScenarioContext.Current.Set("_nextReEnrollmentWindow", something);` anywhere in your code?  I suspect not.

Given the way you have asked the question I'm suspecting that you expect the `ScenarioContext.Current.Get<PensionAssessmentDates>("_nextReEnrollmentWindow")` call to get you the current instance of the page object of type `PensionAssessmentDates` and then get the element using the selector `_nextReEnrollmentWindow`. This is not how it works.

you want to do one of two things I believe. Either add your page object `PensionAssessmentDates` to the `ScenarioContext.Current` and then get the page object out and call the method which uses the private field `_nextReEnrollmentWindow`.

Or (much better in my opinion) ditch your use of the `ScenarioContext.Current` altogether and instead create objects which hold your page objects and let [Specflows internal DI framework provide those to your step classes using context injection](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Context-Injection).

Comment: its worth noting that `ScenarioContext.Current` is not usable when your tests are run in parallel and is likely to be made obsolete at some point (probably the next major release). IMHO context injection is a much better solution, allowing you to keep related functionality together and not just putting every single piece of shared data in a single big dictionary

Comment: Thanks, a colleague showed my my **DOH** error - I was using `"_nextReEnrollmentWindow` as the key, when it should be `ScenarioContext.Current.Get<PensionAssessmentDates>("PensionAssessmentDates")` ....

Comment: Great, glad you got it sorted. I would seriously consider  context injection over using the `ScenarioContext.Current` for reasons given previously...

Comment: I have passed this on, but we have hundreds of regression tests ... so lot's to do! Thanks again